# OpenCV is failing to read ONNX file after Py made into EXE via Pyinstaller

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

I've read around and still do not know why this occurs. The below error occurs after attempting to use OpenCV for my application which detects a face in an image/live camera feed. I use pyinstaller's --onefile to put it into a single executable. Everything runs fine when it isn't an exe and I'm using python to run it.

```
Printing running directory parent
C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI320842\mtcnn_cv2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "new_kiv.py", line 91, in <module>
   File "kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
   File "kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
   File "kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
   File "kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
   File "kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
   File "kivy\base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch_input
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
   File "C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI320842\new_kiv.kv", line 234, in <module>
     on_release: app.runInstant([InstantID.selectedAlgorithm, InstantID.selectedImage, InstantID.outputFolder])
   File "new_kiv.py", line 27, in runInstant
   File "modes\instant.py", line 40, in runInstant
   File "algorithms\mtcnn.py", line 18, in getResult
   File "mtcnn_cv2\mtcnn_opencv.py", line 56, in __init__
 cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:198: error: (-5:Bad argument) Can't read ONNX file: C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI320842\mtcnn_cv2\pnet.onnx in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211004::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'

[16232] Failed to execute script 'new_kiv' due to unhandled exception!
```

Code snippet

```
        pnet_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "pnet.onnx")
        rnet_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "rnet.onnx")
        onet_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "onet.onnx")
        print("Printing running directory parent")
        print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        self._pnet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(pnet_path) ## Errors HERE
        self._rnet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(rnet_path)
        self._onet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX(onet_path)
```

My spec:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['new_kiv.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Shawn\\Documents\\GitHub\\FaceDetection\\virt\\Lib\\site-packages'],
             binaries=[("C:\\Users\\Shawn\\Documents\\GitHub\\FaceDetection\\virt\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64.dll", ".")],
             datas=[('libjpeg-9.dll', '.'),('libpng16-16.dll', '.'),('new_kiv.kv', '.'),('*.kv','.'),('opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64.dll', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['win32timezone','plyer.platforms','plyer.platforms.win.notification', 'plyer.platforms.win.filechooser', 'onnx.onnx_cpp2py_export', 'onnx'],
             hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='new_kiv',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Comment: Does this path exist and does the application have access rights? C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI320842\mtcnn_cv2\pnet.onnx

Comment: Can you catch and print the exception?

Comment: @Micka It printed the same as the output given above:
`Got exception
OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\onnx\onnx_importer.cpp:198: error: (-5:Bad argument) Can't read ONNX file: C:\Users\Shawn\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI444842\mtcnn_cv2\pnet.onnx in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211004::ONNXImporter::ONNXImporter'`

Comment: As far as the path itself, I'm sure it does exist given that I printed "Printing running directory parent" and it printed the mtcnn_cv2 folder being in the temp path, and the pnet.onnx file is in the same directory

Comment: Do you get the same exception if you set the string a non-existing filepath? If the model cant be interpreted you typically get information about which layer failed to load.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a friend of mine found a solution to this. For us, we had to bring "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml" into the main directory (copy/paste it), include it in the `datas` array in our .spec, and edit the haar_cascade file to replace det with `det = cv2.CascadeClassifier(sys._MEIPASS + '\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')` if the _MEIPASS attribute exists.

This is probably something maybe only 1 other person will stumble on, but figured to help that one person whose use-case is this specific. We were extracting face data from this.